# How to Alt Press a Key Using SendKeys in Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, input, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys

I need my batch file to press use the Alt+LeftArrow shortcut and I am using SendKeys to do so. After some looking, I found that you can use the ^, +, and % symbols for control, shift and alt respectively. However,

`%SendKeys% "^{LEFT}"`
correctly inputs the Ctrl+Left shortcut,

`%SendKeys% "+{LEFT}"`
correctly inputs the Shift+Left shortcut, but

`%SendKeys% "%{LEFT}"`
does not correctly input the Alt+Left shortcut and rather just inputs the left key alone. I can confirm that in this program there is an Alt+Left shortcut that works all the time with the keyboard.

It is also worth noting that

`%SendKeys% "^%{LEFT}"`
does not input the Ctrl+Alt+Left shortcut but rather also does the Ctrl+Left input.

I am convinced that % is not the correct symbol and that I am looking for something else. How can I input the Alt+Left shortcut with SendKeys? Thanks.

Comment: Double up the `%` to `%%` to escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Anon Coward

> Double up the `%` to `%%` to escape it.